# Как удалить объект из массива по индексу внутри объекта по клику на данный объект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, события, объекты, динамические-массивы

Всем доброго времени суток.
Очень сильно прошу мне помочь и сильно не бить.
Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо удалить объект из массива по значению **indexOfLi**, только при нажатии на этот элемент.

Код выглядит примерно так:

```
var arrayForSort=[];
var idnexArray = 0;
function addTask(){
        arrayForSort[idnexArray]={indexOfLi:idnexArray,someLi:listItem};
        idnexArray++;
}
```

Где **idnexArray** - числовое значение индекса, **listItem** - элемент который создается на странице при нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

эммм, очень занятно, но мне кажется что можно просто так
   `

```
var arrayForSort=[];
    var idnexArray = 0;
    function addTask(){
        arrayForSort[]={indexOfLi:idnexArray,someLi:listItem};
        idnexArray++;
    }
```

` а если захотите потом удалить элемент из массива то

```
arrayForSort.splice(idnexArray,1);
```

Comment: дело в том, что удалить напрямую у меня не будет возможности.
Есть несколько элементов DOM, которые создаются при нажатии на кнопку и записываются в массив, а потом этот массив уже выводит список элементов на страницу. При этом каждый элемент находится в объекте, чтобы можно было фильтровать по индексу.
И проблема таки заключается в том, что не могу найти решение, как удалить из массива тот объект который содержит элемент по которому нажали на странице.

Comment: очень просто, вы можете передать id кликнутого элемента в функцию и затем выполнить `arrayForSort.indexOf(your_id)` и если функция вернет  значение > -1, то это и будет позиция объекта внутри массива, или еще проще, передать туда индекс элемента и выполнить splice

Comment: подскажите, как это сделать?!
как в массиве 
**arrayForSort[]={indexOfLi:idnexArray,someLi:listItem};**
узнать значение **indexOfLi** только при нажатии на **listItem**, при условии, что в начале все элементы **listItem** идентичны, меняется только значение **indexOfLi**.

**arrayForSort = [{indexOfLi:0,someLi:listItem},{indexOfLi:1,someLi:listItem},{indexOfLi:2,someLi:listItem},{indexOfLi:3,someLi:listItem}];**

как убрать первый объект в массиве если на него нажали, а если на другой, то он убирается из массива.

Помогите, пожалуйста, я новичок в этом и много чего не понимаю

Comment: к примеру вы выводите свой массив на страницу и передаете в обработчик функции индекс массива и при клике на элемент как раз и получите индекс объекта внутри массива (не путать с объектом объектов - у них нет внутри себя индексов), а затем удаляете объект по индексу через splice - попутно можете извлечь id из объекта и выполнить свои действия -  к примеру удалить запись на сервере

Answer (score 0):

Примерно.., тогда то как то так.

```
listItem.addEventListener("onclick", function(e) {
  remove(e.target);
  //функция получит в качестве аргумента объект по которому кликнули
});

function remove(o) {
  // для удаления нужного нам элемента используем свойство объекта в котором хранится индекс
  arrayForSort.splice(o.indexOfLi, 1);
}
```

если я правильно понял ваш вопрос